# VBA Modify Excel COUNTIFS UDF

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA
I have an Excel range of cells that are going to be constantly auto-filtered and a COUNTIFS UDF that will only take into account only the visible (filtered) cells will help me greatly.
I have found this code that seems to be what I need, but it only works for COUNTIF, and not for COUNTIFS
If someone will has any ideas about how to modify it to make it COUNTIFS, would be supergreat!

```
Function Vis(Rin As Range) As Range
'Returns the subset of Rin that is visible

    Dim Cell As Range
    Application.Volatile
    Set Vis = Nothing

    For Each Cell In Rin
        If Not (Cell.EntireRow.Hidden Or Cell.EntireColumn.Hidden) Then
            If Vis Is Nothing Then
                Set Vis = Cell
            Else
                Set Vis = Union(Vis, Cell)
            End If
        End If
     Next Cell
End Function

Function COUNTIFv(Rin As Range, Condition As Variant) As Long
'Same as Excel COUNTIF worksheet function, except does not count
'cells that are hidden

    Dim A As Range
    Dim Csum As Long
    Csum = 0

    For Each A In Vis(Rin).Areas
       Csum = Csum + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(A, Condition)
    Next A

    COUNTIFv = Csum
End Function
```

Comment: Have you considered using `SUBTOTAL` - this can apply a range of math functins (including count) to a range and can optionally process all, or only visible, cells

Comment: No, I haven't, but I will give it a try! Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that doing something like this...

Considering that you have diferent ranges to test with diferent conditions:

```
Function COUNTIFSv(Rin1 As Range, Condition1 As Range, Optional Rin2 As Range, Optional Condition2 As Range, Optional Rin3 As Range, Optional Condition3 As Range) As Long
    'Same as Excel COUNTIF worksheet function, except does not count
    'cells that are hidden

    Dim Csum As Long
    Csum = 0

    If Not IsMissing(Rin3) AND Not IsMissing(Condition3) Then
        Csum = Csum + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Vis(Rin1),Condition1,Vis(Rin2),Condition2,Vis(Rin3),Condition3)
    ElseIf Not IsMissing(Rin2) AND Not IsMissing(Condition2) Then
        Csum = Csum + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Vis(Rin1),Condition1,Vis(Rin2),Condition2)
    Else
        Csum = Csum + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Vis(Rin1),Condition1)
    End If

    COUNTIFSv = Csum
End Function
```

OR You could test the same Range agains different conditions:

```
Function COUNTIFSv(Rin As Range, Condition1 As Range, Optional Condition2 As Range, Optional Condition3 As Range) As Long

    Dim Csum As Long
    Csum = 0

    If Not IsMissing(Condition3) Then
        Csum = Csum + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Vis(Rin),Condition1,Vis(Rin),Condition2,Vis(Rin),Condition3)
    ElseIf Not IsMissing(Condition2) Then
        Csum = Csum + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Vis(Rin),Condition1,Vis(Rin),Condition2)
    Else
        Csum = Csum + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Vis(Rin),Condition1)
    End If

    COUNTIFSv = Csum
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to be working. I tested it against a normal COUNTIFS on the same ranges and COUNTIFS was giving the correct result whereas COUNTIFSv was VALUE!. I tried evaluating but no help. Also when I put in the formula, it doesn't ask for arguments, I don't know if that's normal for an UDF. Thanks for your help anyway! If you can, test it on your end and if it works that means I'm doing something wrong :)